# Getting each function results to show separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each

I have a div, which acts as a landing place for a selection, kind of like a custom selection input. If you click on "Make Selection", a menu appears below. Then your selection (one or more items) will appear in that div.

I am having two issues I cannot figure out.

1. How to get each selection to show wrapped in `.drop-item-selected`, so that the selections look like individual boxes. (Right now the div wraps all the selection choices, if more than one is selected).
2. How to remove the `.drop-item-inputs` if they are checked from the drop down. The commented out javascript is what I tried, but that just removed the whole list.

Anyone have any ideas?

For #1, I am wanting the boxes to be wrapped in the divs, separately, so they appear like this:

[image]

[Here is a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7hc4cLvb/)

```js
$('#proposal-type').click(function() {
  $('#proposal-type-drop').addClass('active');
});
$('.drop-item-input').on('change', function() {
  var proposalVal = "";
  $('.drop-item-input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      proposalVal += $(this).val();
      //$(this).fadeOut();
    };
    /*if ($('.drop-item-input').is(':checked')) {
     $('.drop-item').fadeOut();
    }*/
    $('#proposal-type').val(proposalVal).html("<div class='drop-item-selected'>" + proposalVal + "</div>");
    $('#proposal-type-drop').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#proposal-type-drop {
  width: 45%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#proposal-type-drop.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(data-text)
}

.drop-item {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-item-input {
  display: none;
}

.drop-item-selected {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.proposal-text {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%;
  !important
}

#proposal-check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="proposal-type" contentEditable=true name="proposal_type" class="proposal-input" data-text="Make Selection"></div>
<div id="proposal-type-drop">
  <label class="drop-item">A<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="A"></label>
  <label class="drop-item">B<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="B"></label>
  <label class="drop-item">C<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="C"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to create tags in contentEditable, than you need more logic. For example if someone types 'A', than you need to wrap it in span and check/hide it in drop down list, correct? Also, will you allow typing "F", since it is not in list?

Comment: @skobaljic The tags have nothing to do with the contentEditable. The "tags" I am making are separate inputs that appear with an on click.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what the goal is, what the functionality you need. What you asked in this question is simple, but I doubt the answer will help you, cause I think there is more to do after.

Comment: @skobaljic I added onto my question to clarify.

Comment: OK, for 1 just do [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/7hc4cLvb/1/), creating the html to append after.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Check the answer below. You don't really need each method

Comment: For both check below, it took 1 minute, still doubt that is enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you asked for, just do:

```js
$('#proposal-type').click(function() {
    $('#proposal-type-drop').addClass('active');
});
$('.drop-item-input').on('change', function() {
    var proposalVal = "";
    var proposalHtml = "";
    $('.drop-item-input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            proposalVal += $(this).val();
            proposalHtml += '<span class="drop-item-selected">' + $(this).val() + '</span>';
            $(this).closest('label').fadeOut();
        };
        $('#proposal-type').val(proposalVal).html(proposalHtml);
        $('#proposal-type-drop').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
#proposal-type-drop {
    width: 45%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

#proposal-type-drop.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(data-text)
}

.drop-item {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: .9rem;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-item-input {
    display: none;
}

.drop-item-selected {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
}

.proposal-text {
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
    height: 6em;
    margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%;
    !important
}

#proposal-check {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="proposal-type" contentEditable=true name="proposal_type" class="proposal-input" data-text="Make Selection"></div>
<div id="proposal-type-drop">
    <label class="drop-item">A
        <input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="A">
    </label>
    <label class="drop-item">B
        <input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="B">
    </label>
    <label class="drop-item">C
        <input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="C">
    </label>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hc4cLvb/3/).

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to make it to where the labels appear back into the drop down if they are deleted from the list?

Comment: That's the functionality I was talking about. Sure there is a way, but you did not ask for it.

Comment: How could I do it?

Comment: (sorry for the offtopic) ... but all that stuff is sooo **user unfriendly**... I did not even noticed that after choosing an option there was more to select-to-add....

Comment: I would never do it from scratch, unless I have to. Go search for `jquery tag dropdown` on Google and you will find plenty of plugins, as [this one](http://textextjs.com/). Because I would have more questions now: How to remove from list above? Using keyboard delete or by clicking... etc. Than, there is another stuff I mentioned: What if user types in "F" or "B" in content editable... your script would be tripled.

Comment: @skobaljic I am trying to avoid plugins for performance. This is a fairly simple system that I am hoping to run with minimal code. 

I will be wanting the items to be deleted with either a click or backspace. With the backspace I want to delete the whole word.

Comment: The plugin I mentioned above is 7kb... wish you luck Paul, if you have troubles, just post another question. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
   

 

    $('#proposal-type').click(function() {
          $('#proposal-type-drop').addClass('active');
        });
        $('.drop-item-input').on('change', function() {
          var proposalVal = "";
    
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
              proposalVal += $(this).val();
    $('#proposal-type').append("<div class='drop-item-selected'>" + proposalVal + "</div>&nbsp;");
            $('#proposal-type-drop').removeClass('active');
 $(this).closest('label').fadeOut();
            }
            /*if ($('.drop-item-input').is(':checked')) {
             $('.drop-item').fadeOut();
            }*/
        
         
        });
```

```css
#proposal-type-drop {
  width: 45%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#proposal-type-drop.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(data-text)
}

.drop-item {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-item-input {
  display: none;
}

.drop-item-selected {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.proposal-text {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%;
  !important
}

#proposal-check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="proposal-type" contentEditable=true name="proposal_type" class="proposal-input" data-text="Make Selection"></div>
<div id="proposal-type-drop">
  <label class="drop-item">A<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="A"></label>
  <label class="drop-item">B<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="B"></label>
  <label class="drop-item">C<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="C"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I submitted in hurry. Check now.